# How to create a Views user page?

Tags: views

I'd like to create a users page (author page) where Articles by that user will be displayed.
For example mysite/users/John needs to return teasers of articles that wrote the Author John.

I don't know how to make this when I have names in the URL. I can make the list of recent articles of a user only on paths like mysite/users/1.

This is how my configuration in Views looks like:
[image: View Configuration]

In Content: Author uid I have selected Provide default value --> User ID from URL. From that it only looks for ID and can't recognize a name in the URL (i'm using pathauto).

Answer (score 0):

In your contextual filter settings select "provide default value" -> "user id from url" and it will work.

Comment: This only works when my URL is users/1 or any other number, not when my URL is users/John or any other name.